# Top principal components versus most significant random forest variables

Tags: machine-learning, pca, random-forest, supervised-learning

I was working on making a supervised learning model starting with a database of about 100 features and 1000 data entries. My goal is to predict a certain target variable. I tried three different methods to do dimension reduction:

#1 Principal component analysis, followed by scree plot criteria led to about 10 main PCs with cumulative variance percentage reaching 90 for the PC set.

#2 Regression analysis starting with all 100 variables and then the top 10 variables according to their p-values were chosen.

#3 Random forest on all 100 variables and then the top 10 according to variable importance plot were chosen.

Then starting with the 10 variables from each of the top 3 methods I redid the random forest regression. Results with #3 and #2 feature sets were quite similar in RMSE and $R^2$, while #1 feature set was drastically under-performing.

I know that these dimension reduction methods might not be ideal. But my question is about why I got such results. Why is it that principal components, which I expect to capture the most important information,  under-perform compared with the other two feature sets, while the model (RF) and number of features are the same?

Comment: It's been a while, but I learned that PCA was an unsupervised method... In your approach #1, die you combine PCA with an other method? How did you include the response variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PCA maximizes variance captured by linear combinations of your input variables. There are several reasons why this might not extract useful information about your outcome variable:

- Maximizing variance does not mean maximizing dispersion if your variables are not approximately normally distributed;
- $>90\%$ of the variance in the *input* might be captured by your approach, but since this is an unsupervised technique, it might as well be that the last 10% correlates strongest with the *output*;
- The other techniques you use return significance/variable importance based on the output: You are comparing an unsupervised approach to supervised approaches.

On a different note, why bother with dimension reduction at all? It seems you have plenty of observations to estimate 100 features. If you suspect some to be less informative than others, why not go with a regularized approach (e.g. ridge regression), or a method that inherently does variable selection... say... a random forest?

Comment: (+1) ridge, as well as lasso.